# Get input field value without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, variables

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have this form. One text field and one submit button.
I want to store the string that the user will enter in the text field in a php variable to use it later. Is that possible?

Comment: You don't need ajax to get value from input field and generate a link. Show us your code and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @shaggy I am trying to do it with Ajax that's why I have the post variable there. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax in combination with jquery if you'd like and pass the response from your request immediately to the input. Something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a").on('click', function(){
   var inputval = $("#changeText").val();
   var postdata = {inputval: inputval};
   var url = "http://...";

   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       method: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
       success: function(response) {
         $("#changeText").val(response.data);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Seems right but I can't make it work. I want to send the data to the same page without refreshing the page. So the url would be empty right?

Comment: No, there has to be a url, either an html file path, or a function() path. It depends on the structure of your data. It will call the php part which tries to read yout post request.

Comment: But if you have your data ready from php and you just want to pass it to your value, do it immediately, you don't need ajax. Ajax, you, will use it only after a new input from html and then send this data to php.  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['action'];?>" class="form-control" id="changeText" placeholder="Tracking Number:">

Comment: ok but how can I use it when creating the link?
Can I do something like href= "<?php echo base_url('xxxx'.$_POST['action']) ?> ?

Comment: if you want to pass your input field into the url link you can pass it as query link like for example: base_url('xxxx?action='.$_POST['action']). But this would be a "GET" method not a "POST", and php would read it with $_GET. But since you are sending data to php, it is recommended to be a POST method. So you don't pass the action value to your url, you do it like on my example. It can be a stringified object which you have to read from php respectively with $_POST. Print this value on php to see what you have there.

Comment: I just want the string from the text field to store it in a php variable.
The value is empty.

Comment: You are passing the $_POST['results'] immediately into the same html. Your post request is not triggered from anyone in order to be read. This will not work the way you want to. Please provide the php code in order to get a more clear understanding.

Comment: I edit the content. The issue is still the same I just simplified the context

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help